# php cookies set Hide and show div once i clink on the Hide&Show button

Tags: javascript, show-hide, setcookie

I have made a button `<onclick="define_v();">` to hide and show the div.

Now I want to set the cookies to set the last action.

Here is the JS that i write.

```
<script>
var y=1;
function define_v(){
if(y == 1){
comeout();
y = 0;
} else if(y == 0){
  comein();
  y = 1;
  }
}

function comeout(){
t6 = new Tween(document.getElementById('sideslide').style,'right',Tween.
regularEaseOut,-300,0,.5,'px');
t6.start();
}

function comein(){
t5 = new Tween(document.getElementById('sideslide').style,'right',Tween.
regularEaseOut,0,-300,.5,'px');
t5.start();
}
</script>
```

Comment: *"Need help here!!!"* Need 1) To fix that stuck '!' key. 2) To ask a question. 3) To read the tags before you go slapping them on a question.  This relates to JavaScript, but not Java.

Comment: How should i write it for document.cookie